# TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Attachment

Tags: python, typeerror, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to fix an issue with a log module with my discord bot. I'm getting the error `TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Attachment`

`cogs\core.py", line 351, in on_message_delete
    delmessage.add_field(name='**Attachment**', value='[{filename}]({url})'.format(**attachment), inline=True)
TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Attachment`

I'm not sure whats causing this.

Heres what I'm working with:

```
async def on_message_delete(self, message):
    guild = message.guild
    author = message.author
    bot_member = guild.me
    time = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    now = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    if author.bot:
        return
    if not guild:
        return
    cleanmsg = message.content
    for i in message.mentions:
        cleanmsg = cleanmsg.replace(i.mention, str(i))
    name = author
    name = " ~ ".join((name.name, name.nick)) if name.nick else name.name
    changes = True
    if author.id != self.bot.user.id:
        infomessage = "A message by {} was deleted.".format(message.author.mention, message.channel.mention)
        delmessage = discord.Embed(description=infomessage, colour=discord.Color.purple(), timestamp=time)
        delmessage.add_field(name="Message:", value=cleanmsg)
        delmessage.set_footer(text="ID: {}".format(message.author.id))
        delmessage.set_author(name=name + "'s message was deleted.", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        if message.attachments:
            for attachment in message.attachments:
                delmessage.add_field(name='**Attachment**', value='[{filename}]({url})'.format(**attachment), inline=True)
        await self.bot.send_log_message(guild, embed=delmessage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unpack objects to get their attributes (unless the object is specifically designed to do that).  Instead, you can write your format string to access attributes via dot notation:

```
delmessage.add_field(name='**Attachment**', value='[{0.filename}]({0.url})'.format(attachment), inline=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick I tried something similar like this. I also tried this  `if message.attachments:
                for attachment in message.attachments:
                    delmessage.add_field(name='**Attachment**', value='[{0.filename}]({0.url})'.format(attachment), inline=True)`

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me

Comment: When testing a image delete in the server it doesn't show up in the log as intended.

Comment: I could get your code to work for file uploads (dragging and dropping an image in the chat window, for example.) So for a file named `image.png` i could get an embed with that filename as a link to the image.

Comment: There must be an indentation issue perhaps? I'll have another look.

Answer (score 1):

Some information for the OP. Access to any links this way will not work. Discord has recently changed how images are cached. If you access the image before it's deleted you're able to get a cached copy otherwise if it's deleted before you access it is gone for good.

Embedding a link and accessing it will only return a 403 error.